# Production Level Hive and Sqoop Configuration

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs, sqoop, production-environment

I have some questions regarding HIVE configuration on a production level.
If have a HDFS setup remotely:

1. Where would I have to install Hive so that I can run HQL queries based on the data in HDFS? What all configurations need to be made in Hive?
2. Where would the metastore db be located?
3. If I want to install Sqoop, so that it can extract data from local RDBMS to remote HDFS, where should it be installed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hive Server shall be installed on a Master Node like HDFS NameNode and Secondary NameNode (see this sample schema http://pivotalhd.docs.pivotal.io/docs/01-RawContent/Getting-Started/PHD2_Typical_Cluster_Topology.png). But you also need to install YARN.

Sqoop is usually installed on a client (edge) node.

If you use a distribution like Hortonworks or Cloudera, they include a manager with wizards to ease deployment of all services like Hive, YARN, HBase, etc.

Comment: This should do. Thank you :)